# Problem with implicit declaration of function in objective c

Tags: objective-c, function, declaration

I trying to learn a bit more about Objective-c, and at the moment i'm stuck. I got 4 errors, all the same. "Implicit declaration of function", I googled it but i didn't find a solution.

RadioStation .h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface RadioStation : NSObject {
  NSString* name;
  double frequency;
  char band;
}
+(double)minAMFrequency;
+(double)maxAMFrequency;
+(double)minFMFrequency;
+(double)maxFMFrequency;
-(id)initWithName:(NSString*)newName atFrequency:(double)newFrequency withBand:(char)newBand;
-(NSString*)name;
-(double)frequency;
-(char)band;
-(void)setName:(NSString*)newName;
-(void)setFrequency:(double)newFrequency;
-(void)setBand:(char)newBand;
@end
```

RadioStation .m

```
#import "RadioStation.h"

@implementation RadioStation
+(double)minAMFrequency{
 return 520.0;
};
+(double)maxAMFrequency{
     return 1610.0;
};
+(double)minFMFrequency{
 return 88.3;
};
+(double)maxFMFrequency{
 return 107.9;
};
-(id)initWithName:(NSString*)newName atFrequency:(double)newFrequency withBand:(char)newBand{
 self = [super init];
 if(self != nil){
  name = [newName retain];
  band = newBand;
  if (band == 'F') {
   if (newFrequency > maxFMFrequency()) {
    frequency = maxFMFrequency();
   }else if (newFrequency < minFMFrequency()) {
    frequency = minFMFrequency();
   }else {
    frequency = newFrequency;
   }

  }else if (band == 'A') {
   if (newFrequency > maxAMFrequency()) {
    frequency = maxAMFrequency();
   }else if (newFrequency < minAMFrequency()) {
    frequency = minAMFrequency();
   }else {
    frequency = newFrequency;
   }
  }
 }
 return self;
}
@end
```

The lines

```
if (newFrequency > maxFMFrequency()) {
if (newFrequency < minFMFrequency()) {
if (newFrequency > maxAMFrequency()) {
if (newFrequency < minAMFrequency()) {
```

all say "Implicit declaration of function"

Thanx in advance,
Dietger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might be because you're mixing C and Objective C syntax.

Try:

```
if (newFrequency > [self maxFMFrequency])
```

Comment: this returned an invalid operands to binary >

Comment: Hmm... Perhaps Mark or theChris could enlighten us as to why. It'll be worth a vote-up from me!

Comment: the problem is that when you access the method as if it were an instance method as you are doing above, it returns a pointer and the compiler assumes you want to do a binary operation on it.  > is not a binary operator so it throws that error.  I appreciate your effort, but this answer is NOT correct as stated by the OP in the comment above so not sure why it was picked.  Must be your lucky day! :)

Answer (score 9):

These are class methods so you will need to change each of them as follows:

```
if (newFrequency > [RadioStation maxFMFrequency]) {
if (newFrequency < [RadioStation minFMFrequency]) {
if (newFrequency > [RadioStation maxAMFrequency]) {
if (newFrequency < [RadioStation minAMFrequency]) {
```

Comment: Thx, this was the solution for my prolem

Comment: Would the correct wording be "class methods" rather than "instance methods"?

Comment: @Dave, yip! I saw that I wrote static and "corrected" it without thinking, whoops.  Good catch, thanks.

Comment: probably better to use `[[self class] maxFMFrequency]` etc. in case a subclass would override the class methods to return different constants.

Comment: Please mark this answer as the correct one. Or at least one that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing up methods and functions.

the code you call the thing with

```
if (newFrequency > maxFMFrequency()) {
```

expects to see a declaration of a function like

```
double maxFMFrequency()
```

implemented as a C function - this will not be able to get data from the object so you need to use a methof

the header does declare a method as

```
+(double)maxFMFrequency;
```

but needs to be called as

```
if (newFrequency > [RadioStation maxFMFrequency])
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem. sorted by modifying the function call as given below

```
//function declaration 
-(void) downloadPage:(NSString *)url;

//function definition 
-(void) downloadPage:(NSString *)url
{
userOutput.text = url;
}

//and now the fixed call to downloadPage

-(IBAction) onButtonOneClicked:(id) sender
{
userOutput.text = @"please wait...";
    //fixed call to downloadPage
[self downloadPage:[userInput text]];
}
```